# How to give model-viewer loader color as red

Tags: javascript, three.js, model-viewer

Using model-viewer (https://modelviewer.dev/examples/loading/index.html#glbModel)
I want to give loading color of my `model-viewer` as red but I did not find anything related to that in the documentation.

[image]

Here is codepen link: https://codepen.io/luxonauta/pen/vYKYppq?editors=1010

```html
<!-- Loads <model-viewer> for modern browsers-->
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer@latest/dist/model-viewer.js"></script>
<!-- Loads <model-viewer> for old browsers like IE11-->
<script type="nomodule" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer@latest/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js"></script>

<main>
  <section class="has-dflex-center">
    <div class="lx-container-80">
      <div class="lx-row">
        <div class="lx-card bs-lg">
          <model-viewer src="https://cdn.glitch.com/36cb8393-65c6-408d-a538-055ada20431b/Astronaut.glb?1542147958948" ios-src="https://cdn.glitch.com/36cb8393-65c6-408d-a538-055ada20431b/Astronaut.usdz?v=1569545377878" poster="https://cdn.glitch.com/36cb8393-65c6-408d-a538-055ada20431b%2Fposter-astronaut.png?v=1599079951717" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut!" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls="true" auto-rotate="true" ar="true"></model-viewer>
          <p class="text"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> This pen is a basic demo of the &lt;model-viewer&gt; web component. It makes displaying 3D and AR content on the web easy!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Codepen link demo is fully working only red color is not implemented here: https://codepen.io/luxonauta/pen/vYKYppq?editors=1010

Please help me thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should apply [custom css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).

```
model-viewer {
  --progress-bar-color: red;
}
```

Comment: your answer worked !!!  here is demo of that https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/KKXJPzr , thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily change the background color with CSS. Right now your demo has

```css
model-viewer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25rem;
  background-color: #70bcd1;
}
```

Just change the background color to red:

```css
model-viewer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25rem;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

[image]

Comment: i'm able to change the background as you said, but i want to change `loader`  color as pointed by arrow in my uploaded image.

Comment: In my real scenario i want background color as back  and loader color as red